# chaining sql queries in a WITH clause to eventually perform an update

Tags: postgresql, testing, common-table-expression

I am trying to populate a test db with a bunch of objects for a very specific integration test and I am having trouble using the returned id's from a one of the queries as the values for the subsequent object's fields.

```sql
-- create a user with an account with salesforce integration
WITH p AS (
        INSERT INTO person (email, confirmed, first_name, last_name) VALUES
        ('test3@example.com', TRUE, 'Salesforce', 'Guy')
        RETURNING id
     ),
     ac AS (
        INSERT INTO account (subscription_type, subscription_expires_on, salesforce_integration) VALUES (0, '2024-10-10', TRUE)
        RETURNING id
     ),
     am AS (
        INSERT INTO account_member (person_id, account_id, admin) VALUES
        ((SELECT p.id FROM p), (SELECT ac.id FROM ac), TRUE)
        RETURNING account_id, person_id
     ),
     la AS (
        -- create a salesforce linked_account
        INSERT INTO linked_account (person_id, provider_id, access_token) VALUES
        ((SELECT p.id FROM p), 'salesforce', '00DC00000016x37!AQIAQIt5EpCIgTFl9hg2qF9Ed6vzLJmTg9Nrd.uxvVva5WaxzMChn4sBBgV6KXiICCBoJgcFYbrTqpFtFJwpd.B7fe5kG9_z')
        RETURNING id
    ),
     v AS (
        -- create a video and take
        INSERT INTO video (person_id, account_id) VALUES
        ((SELECT p.id FROM p), (SELECT ac.id FROM ac))
        RETURNING id
    ),
     t AS (
        INSERT INTO take (video_id, key, duration, state, thumbnail_selected) VALUES
        ((SELECT v.id FROM v), 'g1/g1546ad07eff44c397e356be7c4bea49/g1546ad07eff44c397e356be7c4bea49', 35, 2, 1)
        RETURNING id
    )
    -- update video with selected take
    UPDATE video SET selected_take_id = (SELECT id FROM take WHERE take.video_id=video.id);
```

The issue I am running into is when the test is run it states that the video (v) I created does not have a selected_take_id set, which means that "update video with selected take" query at the bottom did not in fact work.

It is important to note that this DB is not empty when this script is run, there are 2 other similar seed files that run before this so there areat least 2 videos, 2 takes etc. already stored in the db. If anyone knows how to make this work without having to provide static id's as values for the foreign keys it would save me a ton of time.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the associated schema, perhaps as a http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: I figured it out but thanks for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the UPDATE (the "main query") to find a row that is inserted in the same SQL statement, a row that doesn't exist at the start of the statement.

If that's the case, this can't work as documented in [Data-Modifying Statements in WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) :

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so **they cannot "see" each others' effects
>   on the target tables**. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between
>   different WITH sub-statements and the main query

You probably want to use a [DO block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) instead with several queries laid out in procedural form in pl/pgsql.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel-Vérité. That's def what is happening because if I run this same query in the psql command line twice, it updates the take from the first call... I guess I just have to finish the insert query before trying to run that update.